# yum list installedについて

Tags: yum

yum list installedで表示されるパッケージは全てユーザが手動で追加したものなのでしょうか。
それともシステムが自動でインストールしたパッケージも含まれているのでしょうか。
また、ミドルウェア・アプリケーション単位で関連するパッケージをツリー形式で表示するなどの方法はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

既にご存じかとも思いますが、`yum` コマンドではパッケージの依存関係を解決して足りないパッケージを追加インストールするので、自分自身がコマンドで指定したパッケージ以外にもインストールされているケースがままあります。

`yum list installed` で表示されるのは **今現在システムにインストールされているパッケージ一覧** と考えてください。

「関連するパッケージをツリー表示」も、標準のコマンドでは出来ないと思います。